# Coded UI - How to have configuraable URL's?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I created simple Coded UI test where I do the following:

1. Open a browser
2. Go to a web address
3. Click on a hyperlink (link within the webapp's domain).

After the UIMapping is generated I see a bunch of auto-generated mapping code. Within the UIMapping file (class) I see URL's which are essentially hard-coded.

Example:

```
this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.PageUrl] = "http://mytesturl:8000";
this.mUIItem50006598Hyperlink.FilterProperties[HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.Href] = "http://mytesturl:8000/link"
```

How can I make my automated UI tests configurable so that I can run the same tests against different environments (dev, test, prod...etc)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a test many times with data read from .csv file (data driving)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469100/how-to-run-a-test-many-times-with-data-read-from-csv-file-data-driving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adrian mentioned this is an oft-repeated question with no clear answer. You can find a little information on my approach [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239523/execute-coded-ui-tests-in-multiple-environments).

The short story is that you won't be able to dynamically configure an environment if you're relying on the CodedUI mapping functionality unless your test methods:

- Call a helper method to navigate to a base URL, which in turn is decided on *some sort* of data driven configuration (An XML/app.config file, a CSV, a spreadsheet). You can find info on how to do that on my question in the link above.
- Call your mapper-generated method. When creating it be sure to assume that you're only navigating from the base URL, not opening your browser etc.

So your code will look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public static void GenericTestMethod() {
    //get browserWindow from your test setup method etc.
    GoToEnvironmentBaseUrl(browserWindow);
    MapperGeneratedCodedUiMethod();
    AssertStuff();
}

public static void GoToEnvironmentBaseUrl(BrowserWindow browserWindow) {
    browserWindow.NavigateToUrl(new Uri("http://www."
            + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EnvironmentURLMod")
            + ".com"));
}
```